# Why I got this date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is my code:

```
DateTime dataCreazioneImmagineWebcam = immagineWebcam.CreationTime;
Response.Write(dataCreazioneImmagineWebcam.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

and it prints `01 01 1601 01:00:00`, when if I analyze file in Explorer the date is correct (4 February 2014).

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist, this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

So apparently `immagineWebcam` does not reflect a file that exists.

Comment: +1 didn't know about this *feature* of FileInfo. I would expect some exception instead